# React Native - Memoize Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app, where the user has to choose different options, like food they like and etc. The following screen is gender selection. I'm using a button group to make a selection, but when I got to the next screen and come back to to the previous screen the selection is gone. I'm using context to save to cache, in the console is says its been save, but on the screen. I did a bit of research and I think useMemo or callBack would be the best approach, unless someone suggests a different method. I'm just not sure on how to implement that. Basically I just want to save updated state using hooks.

```
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(''); 

  const buttons = ['Male', 'Female'];

    const memoizedCallaback = React.useCallback((index) => {
      setSelected(index);
    });

    return (
      <View>
        <ButtonGroup
          buttons={buttons}
          selectedIndex={selected}
          onPress={memoizedCallaback}
          buttonStyle={{ borderEndColor: 100 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  });
```

Comment: `I'm using context to save to cache` I don't see any code in your question that does that.

Comment: Those hooks (useMemo, useCallback) will only help you ***while*** the component is mounted. Once you unmount and go elsewhere, then come back and remount you'll need to resync the UI "state" with what was saved to "cache"/context/etc... Does this make sense?

Comment: Yea it makes sense now, I need to focus on the context instead. Thanks for that, I just didn't wanted to spend a lot of time on something that won't help to solve my issue.